# Pandas - expand dataframe using daterange

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
 name    from       amount   days
 A       7/31/18    200      1
 B       7/31/18    300      1
 C       7/30/18    200      1
 D       7/27/18    100      3
 ......
 G       7/17/18    50       1
 H       7/13/18    150      4
```

I'd like to expand it to this, where days does not equal 1:

```
 name    from       amount   days
 A       7/31/18    200      1
 B       7/31/18    300      1
 C       7/30/18    200      1
 D       7/29/18    100      3
 D       7/28/18    100      3
 D       7/27/18    100      3
 ......
 G       7/17/18    50       1
 H       7/16/18    150      4
 H       7/15/18    150      4
 H       7/14/18    150      4
 H       7/13/18    150      4
```

If possible, I'd also like to add a column that can distinguish between the original data and expanded data (since I'm going to need to filter some dates eventually):

```
 name    from       amount   days   original
 A       7/31/18    200      1      1
 B       7/31/18    300      1      1
 C       7/30/18    200      1      1
 D       7/29/18    100      3      0
 D       7/28/18    100      3      0
 D       7/27/18    100      3      1
 ......
 G       7/17/18    50       1      1
 H       7/16/18    150      4      0
 H       7/15/18    150      4      0
 H       7/14/18    150      4      0
 H       7/13/18    150      4      1
```

Edit: **To clarify the expansion:** Days will tell you how many rows it needs to be expanded to. Alternatively, you can use the date above the original value as a boundary (the entry 7/27 where days=3 will stop at the above value where the date is 7/30. The data has constraints to make sure it never overlaps).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About two steps create the dataframe(`reindex`) , and adjust the values (`duplicated`)

```
newdf=df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df.days)) # create the df using reindex
adddate=pd.Series(np.concatenate(df.days.apply(np.arange).values),index=newdf.index)# create the timedelta to add 
newdf['from']=pd.to_datetime(newdf['from'])+pd.to_timedelta(adddate,unit='d')# assign the value 
newdf['original']=(~newdf.index.duplicated()).astype(int)
newdf
Out[240]: 
  name       from  amount  days  original
0    A 2018-07-31     200     1         1
1    B 2018-07-31     300     1         1
2    C 2018-07-30     200     1         1
3    D 2018-07-27     100     3         1
3    D 2018-07-28     100     3         0
3    D 2018-07-29     100     3         0
```

Comment: The only minor nitpick is it would be awesome if the dates were in the right order. But that's not important for what I'm working towards. This answer is excellent, thank you.

Comment: @piRSquared that is great sir

Answer (score 4):

#### Comprehension

```
df['from'] = pd.to_datetime(df['from'])

pd.DataFrame([
    (n, f, a, d, int(f == F))
    for n, F, a, d in zip(*map(df.get, df))
    for f in pd.date_range(F, periods=d)[::-1]
], columns=[*df.columns] + ['original'])

   name       from  amount  days  original
0     A 2018-07-31     200     1         1
1     B 2018-07-31     300     1         1
2     C 2018-07-30     200     1         1
3     D 2018-07-29     100     3         0
4     D 2018-07-28     100     3         0
5     D 2018-07-27     100     3         1
6     G 2018-07-17      50     1         1
7     H 2018-07-16     150     4         0
8     H 2018-07-15     150     4         0
9     H 2018-07-14     150     4         0
10    H 2018-07-13     150     4         1
```

---

#### Helper Functions

I edited my answer to use `duplicated` instead of `cum_count`.  I got the idea from [@Wen's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52205832/2336654)

```
def f(x):
  return pd.date_range(
      pd.to_datetime(x).min(),
      periods=len(x)
  ).sort_values(ascending=False)

def g(d):
  return d.groupby('name')['from'].transform(f)

def h(d):
  return 1 - d.name.duplicated(keep='last')

df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.days)].assign(**{'from': g, 'original': h})

  name       from  amount  days  original
0    A 2018-07-31     200     1         1
1    B 2018-07-31     300     1         1
2    C 2018-07-30     200     1         1
3    D 2018-07-29     100     3         0
3    D 2018-07-28     100     3         0
3    D 2018-07-27     100     3         1
4    G 2018-07-17      50     1         1
5    H 2018-07-16     150     4         0
5    H 2018-07-15     150     4         0
5    H 2018-07-14     150     4         0
5    H 2018-07-13     150     4         1
```

Comment: Definitely a helpful answer but not quite what I'm looking for (since the from column is repeating the dates rather than filling in as a range).

Comment: @JesusMonroe I missed that completely.  I'll delete my answer.